# c++ floats and valgrind strange behaviour

Tags: c++, floating-point, segmentation-fault, valgrind, stringstream

I have valgrind 3.6.0, I've searched everywhere and found nothing.

The problem is that when I'm trying to access a float number while using valgrind, I get a segfault, but when I run the program as is, without valgrind, everythings goes as expected.

This is the piece of code:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    void end() {
        float f;
        f = 1.23;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << f;
        std::cout << ss.str();
    }
};

extern "C" void clean_exit_on_sig(int sig) {
    //Code logging the error
    mc->end();
    exit(1);
}

MyClass *mc;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    signal(SIGINT , clean_exit_on_sig);
    signal(SIGABRT , clean_exit_on_sig);
    signal(SIGILL , clean_exit_on_sig);
    signal(SIGFPE , clean_exit_on_sig);
    signal(SIGSEGV, clean_exit_on_sig);
    signal(SIGTERM , clean_exit_on_sig);
    mc = new MyClass();
    while(true) {
        // Main program loop
    }
}
```

When I press Control+C, the program catches the signal correctly and everything goes fine, but when I run the program using valgrind, when tries to execute this command `ss << f; // (Inside MyClass)` a segfault is thrown :-/

I've tried this too:

```
std::string stm = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(f);
```

But I keep on receiving a segfault signal when boost acceses the float number too.

This is the backtrace when I get segfault with boost:

```
./a.out(_Z17clean_exit_on_sigi+0x1c)[0x420e72]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x32920)[0x593a920]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0x7eb29)[0x51e6b29]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNKSt7num_putIcSt19ostreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE15_M_insert_floatIdEES3_S3_RSt8ios_baseccT_+0xd3)[0x51e8f43]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNKSt7num_putIcSt19ostreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE6do_putES3_RSt8ios_basecd+0x19)[0x51e9269]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_+0x9f)[0x51fc87f]
./a.out(_ZN5boost6detail26lexical_stream_limited_srcIcSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEES4_E9lcast_putIfEEbRKT_+0x8f)[0x42c251]
./a.out(_ZN5boost6detail26lexical_stream_limited_srcIcSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEES4_ElsEf+0x24)[0x42a150]
./a.out(_ZN5boost6detail12lexical_castISsfLb0EcEET_NS_11call_traitsIT0_E10param_typeEPT2_m+0x75)[0x428349]
./a.out(_ZN5boost12lexical_castISsfEET_RKT0_+0x3c)[0x426fbb]
./a.out(This line of code corresponds to the line where boost tries to do the conversion)
```

and this is with the default stringstream conversion:

```
./a.out(_Z17clean_exit_on_sigi+0x1c)[0x41deaa]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x32920)[0x593a920]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0x7eb29)[0x51e6b29]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNKSt7num_putIcSt19ostreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE15_M_insert_floatIdEES3_S3_RSt8ios_baseccT_+0xd3)[0x51e8f43]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNKSt7num_putIcSt19ostreambuf_iteratorIcSt11char_traitsIcEEE6do_putES3_RSt8ios_basecd+0x19)[0x51e9269]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_+0x9f)[0x51fc87f]
./a.out(This line of code corresponds to the line where I try to do the conversion)
```

`a.out` is my program, and I run valgrind this way: `valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out`

Another weird thing is that when I call `mc->end();` while the program runs fine (Any signal received, Object just finished his work), I don't get segfault in any way (as is and with valgrind).

Please, don't tell me 'Don't close your program with Control+C blah blah...' this piece of code is for logging any error the program possibly have without losing data in case of segfault, killing it because of deadlock or something else.

**EDIT:** Maybe is a valgrind bug (I don't know, searched on google but found nothing, don't kill me), any workaround will be accepted too.

**EDIT2:** Just realized that boost calls ostream too (Here is clearer than using vim :-/), going to try sprintf float conversion.

**EDIT3:** Tried this `sprintf(fl, "%.1g", f);` but still crashes, backtrace:

```
./a.out(_Z17clean_exit_on_sigi+0x40)[0x41df24]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x32920)[0x593a920]
/lib64/libc.so.6(sprintf+0x56)[0x5956be6]
./a.out(Line where sprintf is)
```

Comment: I don't think your signal handler is async-safe. You're not allowed to do complicated stuff in a signal handler.

Comment: Workaround: Put `printf("%f", f);` in your signal handler instead.

Comment: Kerrek SB, I know, but without valgrind everything works fine so I think I'm not doing complicated stuff because works. I need to put the float inside a string and tried to do this: `sprintf(fl, "%.1g", f);` but still crashes in the same line when accesing the floating point, so I think it's a problem with floating points. I think I'm going to multiply it by 10 and cast it to an integer.

Comment: "Everything works fine" is a red herring. UB is UB, even if it looks "fine".

Comment: (You're also missing `extern "C"` on your signal handler.)

Comment: I don't know anything about valgrind but I have two thoughts. One is you can just do `cout << some_float;` I suspect the results won't change but worth a try to condemn or exonerate stringstream. Also while using an older version of the GNU C++ compiler I discovered a similar problem when using multiple tasks. There was a reentrancy bug in the lower level libraries.  If ValGrind exercises your code with extra tasks it might be exposing this bug. In the toolchain I use this was corrected a couple of years back.

Comment: Wow, all that is new for me @Kerrec, going to read about async-safe signals and about `extern "C"`. Thanx for your info. And @Tod, I have the latest version of the compiler, btw I'm going to check some things about that. Thanx for you help.

Comment: I read in the valgrind documentation about the `--trace-signals=<yes|no> [default: no]` flag, it says `Enable or disable tracing of signal handling.` Perhaps you get a clue to what is wrong if you use it?

Comment: Nice point PuraVida, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some hours of reading and research, I found the problem, I'm going to answer my own question because noone does, only a comment by @Kerrek SB [ https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb ] but I cannot accept a comment. (Thank you)

It's as easy as inside a signal handler you only can call a bunch of functions safely: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html

If you call some non-async-safe functions, they can work, but not always.

If you want to call non-async-safe functions inside a signal handler, you can do this:

- Create 2 pipes. `int pip1[2]; int pip2[2]; pipe(pip1); pipe(pip2);`
- Create a new thread and make the thread wait to receive some data from the 1rst pipe `read(pip1[0], msg, 1);`
- When signal handler is called, use `write` async-safe function to write to the 1rst pipe `write(pip1[1], "0", 1);`
- Then make the signal wait for the second pipe with `read(pip2[0], msg, 1);`
- The thread will wake up and do all the job he has to do (saving data to database in this case), after that, make the thread write data to the second pipe `write(pip2[1], "0", 1);`
- Now main thread will wake up and finish with `_Exit(1)` or something else.

Info:

I'm using 2 pipes because if I write to a pipe and just after that I read it, it's possible that the 2nd thread never wakes up because the main thread have read the data have just written. And I'm using a secondary pipe to block the main thread because I don't want it to exit while the 2nd thread is saving data.

Keep in mind that signal handler maybe has been called while modifying a shared resource, if your 2nd thread acceses that resource is possible that you encounter a second segfault, so be careful when accesing shared resources with your 2nd thread (Global variables or something else).

If you are testing with valgrind and don't want to receive 'false' memory leaks when receiving a signal you can do this before exiting `pthread_join(2ndthread, NULL)` and `exit(1)` instead of `_Exit(1)`. These are non-async-safe functions, but at least you can test memory leaks and close you app with a signal without receiving 'false' memory leaks.

Hope this helps someone. Thanks again @Kerrek SB.

Answer (score 0):

Debuggers and stuff sometimes toss signals to the process that you don't normally get.  I had to alter a function that used recv to work under gdb for example.  Check to see what your signal is and verify that mc is not null before trying to use it.  See if that starts getting you closer to an answer.

I am thinking perhaps your use of new (or something else maybe) is possibly causing valgrind to send a signal that is being caught by your handler before mc is initialized.

It's also clear you didn't paste actual code because your use of 'class' without making the end() function public means this should not compile.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it and mc is not null. And yes, this is not the full code because the code is right now some thousands of lines so it's impossible to put real code, just forgot to add `public:`, going to edit it. The signal is sent just when some code tries to acces the floating point, so `new` is not throwing any signal, it's working as expected.